# Number of generators of nontrivial finite abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> (Dummit Foote Exercise 5.2.11) Let $G$ be a nontrivial finite abelian group of rank $t$ (i.e., $G\simeq\Bbb Z/n_1\times\cdots\times\Bbb Z/n_t$ such that $n_{i+1}\mid n_i$ for $1\leq i\leq t-1$).
>
> (a) Prove that the rank of $G$ equals the maximum of the ranks of its Sylow subgroups.
>
> (b) Prove that $G$ can be generated by $t$ elements but no subset with fewer than $t$ elements generates $G$ [One way of doing this is by using part (a) together with Exercise 7.]

I proved (a). For (b), I tried to follow the hint. Suppose $G$ can be generated by $k<t$ elenments. First note that $(\Bbb Z/p)^n$ cannot be generated by elements fewer than $n$. By (a), let $P$ be a rank $t$ Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $\varphi:P\to P$ be a $p$th power map. Then $P/\mbox{im}\varphi\simeq(\Bbb Z/p)^t$. Since $G$ can be generated by $k$ elements, $P$ can be generated by $a\leq k$ many elements so $P/\mbox{im}\varphi$ can be generated by $a$ elements which is a contradiciton.

Problem here is that I used the fact that $P$ can be generated by $a\leq k$ elements. The concept of free group appears after this exercise. How can I prove this problem then?

> Exercise 7. Let $p$ be a prime an $A = \langle x_1\rangle\times\cdots\times\langle x_n\rangle$ be an abelian $p$-group, where $|x_i| = p^{\alpha_i}>1$ for all $i$. Define the $p$th power map $\varphi:A\to A$ by $x\mapsto x^p$. Then $\ker\varphi$ and $A/\mbox{im}\varphi$ have rank $n$ and both are isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/p)^n$.

Comment: your definition of "rank" is not well-defined. What is the rank of $C_6 \cong C_2\times C_3$?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Edit the post. I meant the invariant factor form.

Comment: Still unclear. Are $k$, $s$ and $t$ all the same?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Yes. Sorry for confusion. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ can be generated by $s<t$ elements. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ of rank $t$. We can write $G=P\times Q$. Now also $P\cong G/Q$ can be generated by $s$ elements. By Exercise 7, there is a quotient $P/P_1\cong C_p^t$ which is also generated by $s$ elements. Contradiction.